# How to use pam_time in a program?

Tags: c, security, pam

I've set up `/etc/security/time.conf` like so:

```
my_program_name;*;!root;Al1000-1200
```

which is supposed to only allow to run my program between 10:00 and 12:00.

Then, I've created `/etc/pam.d/custom_rules` like so:

```
account    required    pam_time.so
```

And finally, in my `my_program.name.c` code, I have:

```
...
int r = pam_start("custom_rules", NULL, &conv, &pamh);
if (r == PAM_SUCCESS) r = pam_authenticate(pamh, 0);
...
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. If I leave `/etc/pam.d/custom_rules` empty, it does ask for login and password, but obviously doesn't apply time.conf rules. If I have `/etc/pam.d/custom_rules` as above, the program finishes without a word.

Answer (score 0):

turns out the `/etc/security/time.conf` should look like this instead:

```
custom_rules;*;!root;Al1000-1200
```